# ¿Cómo puedo moverme infinitamente sobre un lienzo en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy creando una graficadora utilizando flutter, y su lenguaje Dart. Ya dibujé el plano cartesiano, pero ahora necesito que el usuario se pueda desplazar infinitamente por el plano cartesiano, esto, tanto vertical, como horizontalmente.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.